# How to publish TFS project locally?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

A co-worker of mine recently set up TFS for us as our team is growing.

Our IT department setup the server and we cannot publish via FTP or Web Deploy(IT dept. never set it up).

I use to copy the project to the server via remote desktop and open it up in Visual Studio on the server. Then I would do a file system publish to IIS. When I tried this with the TFS project it will not publish. It says published but nothing changes on the website.

The message that shows in the output section is as follows:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ScmPublicPortal, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>C:\Users\alehaney.CA-TO-SC-IIS02\Desktop\ScmPublicPortal\ScmPublicPortal\PublicClasses\LookupWorksheet.cs(16,21,16,28): warning CS0414: The field 'excelHelper.LookupWorksheet.records' is assigned but its value is never used
1>  ScmPublicPortal -> C:\Users\alehaney.CA-TO-SC-IIS02\Desktop\ScmPublicPortal\ScmPublicPortal\bin\ScmPublicPortal.dll
2>------ Publish started: Project: ScmPublicPortal, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
2>Connecting to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SCM...
2>Transformed Web.config using C:\Users\alehaney.CA-TO-SC-IIS02\Desktop\ScmPublicPortal\ScmPublicPortal\Web.Release.config into obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.
2>Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
2>obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp.
2>Publishing folder /...
2>
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Where is your build server installed?  It seems to deploy the package right on the build agent.

Comment: Sorry if i am not answering correctly but i am new to the TFS thing. I think the build server is installed on our testing server, its the same one with TFS installed.

Comment: How did you setup the publish in TFS?

Comment: @MikeCheel I have no idea. I need to ask my co-worker. Again please excuse my ignorance in the matter. I am an intern and have never worked with TFS. When they hired my co-worker he set it up because there are now three of us here and we needed a better way to manage our code.

Answer (score 0):

Which website are you trying to publish to? Because it looks like TFS Build has been configured to publish to the local IIS server (on the TFS Build Server).  I assume you are trying to deploy to a website on another server?  If so you need to setup the publish profile to point to the right place.

Comment: Yes you are right, I need to publish to a different server. I ended up deploying to a package and importing the package to IIS. I was also able to install Web Deploy.